# CSS built with javascript only running on first call

Tags: javascript, css

So i'm trying to create a multiple click function without needing to hold down control like select multiple expects you to, i have this

```
$(function(){
    $('#select-toggle').each(function(){    
        var select = $(this), values = {};    
        $('option',select).each(function(i, option){
            values[option.value] = option.selected;        
        }).click(function(event){        
            values[this.value] = !values[this.value];
            $('option',select).each(function(i, option){            
                option.selected = values[option.value];        
            });    
        });
}); });
```

i have 3 lists which try to use this function, but only the first one displayed can use it it seems and the rest just act as if they are regular "multiple selects". How do i get this to work on all of them?

Please ignore that the selects have no options, or aren't closed, the selects work, and the function works to an extent so extra code isn't needed, this is just to give an example of how it's being used.

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="select-toggle" class="roundedcorners" name="Consoles" size="1"
                    value="'; echo '"/>';
<select multiple="multiple" id="select-toggle" class="roundedcorners" name="Developers" size="1"
                    value="'; echo '"/>';
<select multiple="multiple" id="select-toggle" class="roundedcorners" name="Publishers" size="1"
                    value="'; echo '"/>';
```

These are the three instances i'm trying to use the javascript class on, as it stands the only one it works on is "consoles"

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: Well that was incredibly dumb of me. Simply a case of switching the class and id's around. Thanks :)

Comment: If you just swapped classes and IDs, you still have duplicates, now you have multiple `id=roundedcorners`

Comment: As far as i'm aware, you can't have multiple classes, yes i have multiple roundcorner id's but they have no actual functionality (it's all just about looks) and i don't use the ID either so they serve their purpose (style) and don't interrupt the webpage from working as expected. 
Is there a better way to apply 2 classes to an element?

Comment: You certainly can have multiple classes. You separate them with spaces: `class="roundedcorners select-toggle"`.

Comment: Seems my teachers are as dumb as I am gullible. Thanks for that :) now I have to fix my whole CSS!